# Constrained Quadratic Optimization(Reproducing Kernel)

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, nonlinear-optimization, quadratic-programming

I am attempting to use a constrained quadratic optimization to find the coefficients of a reproducing kernel.

The problem is as follows:

$y(t)=\sum_{i=0}^J\alpha_iK(t, t_i)$

$Q(\alpha)= \alpha^tK\alpha$

The optimization problem looks like this:

Minimize $Q(\alpha)$ such that,
$Gx <= h$,
$Ax = b$

Trying to optimize this using different optimizers(CVXOPT, MOSEK, Scipy) all fail. MOSEK gives the only decent error message, "Primal Infeasible". I don't agree with that given that I know RKHS have unique solutions.

Some things I have checked:

- My kernel matrix is positive definite and symmetric.
- The cost function or $Q(\alpha)$ is always positive.
- My constraint matrices are not full rank (Mosek has a pre-solve that supposedly removes redundant constraints)

I am as sure as possible that I have setup my problem correctly. I am just unsure of what I can do from here to check myself.

Does anyone have any other ways I can possibly figure out where my problem is?

Comment: Very likely cause then is garbage values in $K$, $A$, $b$, $G$ or $h$, i.e., numerically huge / small values. In what range are these values? Can you solve the feasibility problem? Can you solve it when you remove the inequalities? Remove the equalities?

Comment: Thanks Johan, So I removed all the constraints and it solves optimally, and it's values are what I would expect for the output of the unconstrained problem. I then only removed the equality constraints and it optimized for 40 iterations before terminating on a singular matrix; it's optimization status was unknown, fit was in the realm of what I would expect. Only equality constraints lead to an error "ValueError: domain error" after 17 iterations. I assume this means that something about my equality constraints is messed up.

Comment: I think I need to reduce the rank of the equality constraint matrix; the matrix rank is usually 4 - 10 below the actual dimension of the matrix. I am going to try and use Gaussian elimination to do it, unless you have a different idea?

Comment: I would expect a solver to be able to handle this as the problem sounds very small, but sure, post-processing the equalities using, e.g., LU/QR/SVD or something would be a quick fix.

Comment: The number of coefficients to fit is around 250 each time. But there are constraints on each point. How would I use SVD to simplify my constraint matrix?

Comment: Too little coffee to give a complete answer on how to actually implement it, just hinting that there are numerical recipes for precisely this, I was a bit worried that you were about to do some manual Gaussian elimination

Comment: To reduce $Ax=b$ using LU I think (one cup later) it should be [L,U] = lu(A);r = find(sum(abs(U),2)>yourzerothreshold);Anew = U(r,:);bnew = L\b;bnew = bnew(1:r);

Comment: Is it correct that $y$ doesn't appear in your optimization problem?  Is it correct that $x$ doesn't appear in the objective, and only appears in constraints?  As it's written, there are no constraints on $\alpha$.  Also, have you tried using CVX?

Comment: littleO: Yes y doesn't appear, because it's "information" is present in the kernel matrix(K). If you're interested reproducing kernels are awesome you should go take a look at them. Thanks for that Johan I figured out how to simplify but I have some other problems going on. Now to find them! Thanks for the help.